# Accessing Android properties in C code

Tags: android, c++

I've been trying to figure this out for a while. I'm trying to store a value in a custom property variable using `property_set` and retrieve it in another module using `property_get` but it's just not working. I made some changes to the `property_service.c` file to add permissions to the custom property but it's still not reading what's stored and there are no errors either. Are there any other files that needs to be changed to get this working?

property_service.c looks like this. I added my custom property (dm) at the end.

```
/* White list of permissions for setting property services. */
struct {
    const char *prefix;
    unsigned int uid;
    unsigned int gid;
} property_perms[] = {
    { "net.rmnet0.",      AID_RADIO,    0 },
        ...
    { "service.adb.tcp.port", AID_SHELL,    0 },
    { "persist.sys.",     AID_SYSTEM,   0 },
    { "persist.service.", AID_SYSTEM,   0 },
    { "persist.security.", AID_SYSTEM,   0 },
    { "dm.", AID_SYSTEM,  0},
    { NULL, 0, 0 }
};
```

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  The answers will be different for the different languages.

Comment: Are the functions `property_set` and `property_get` your functions, android OS functions or some library?  They are not in the C or C++ languages.

Comment: Show...Your...Code. :-)  Paste...Don't...Link.

Comment: `property_set` and `property_get` are Android functions. Code is pretty simple. I have `property_set("dm.scheme",value);` in a function in one file and `char value[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX]; property_get("dm.scheme",value,"0");` in another file. And they're all c++ files.

Answer (score 0):

It can be permission problem, in general case user/group permissions (are you running as root?). 
Second thing that can cause permissions denial is SELinux rules - grep logcat and dmesg logs for "avc" denials. There should be some messages about your efforts in this case. Of course this case is possible if SELinux (e.g. SEAndroid) is running in enforced mode.

Otherwise you should provide more details, like errno, retval and so on